# Randomly fall my bandwidth

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, bandwidth

I know this problem may be several reasons but I am so helpless after I seek but I cannot scout the solutions.

I'am writing some informations, but If not enough I give all the informations you need.

OS: WIN 10 Enterprise (have its license, it's original)
Torrent Client: qBittorrent (maybe run, maybe not)
Browser: Chrome
PC: Asus X550JX
Modem (and also router): Sagemcom
Net: Coax 50/20

The problem:
When I use my pc just normally (youtube, facebook, some torrent stb.) sometimes I am attentive the pages are slowed down to no load, after I see the speed measurement bandwidth is reduced to a fraction.
My temporary solution is I switch off my Wifi on my PC, and immediately afterwards I switch on, and bandwidth is full again.

When the problem appears, I got an error event: 1014 - DNS Client Event...

Please give me advice, whatever you need I give.

Comment: Check out [Event ID: 1014 Source: DNS Client Events](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-1014-source-DNS%20Client%20Events-eventno-10623-phase-1.htm)

Comment: Thanks! One comment is: "On Windows Server 2008 R2 I had to enabled "Spanning Tree Portfast" on my servers switch ports. "

Where can I set enabled?

Comment: [Spanning Tree Portfast](http://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/cisco/spanning-tree-protocol-stp-and-portfast/) is specific to Cisco switches (which you don't have) so that cannot fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I supposed. Well, if I understand correctly you don't have other idei or advice how can I remove the problem.

Comment: Not at the moment. I will look some more later.